# Custom Button click event firing twice

Tags: vb.net, button

```
  Public Class MyNewButton
      Inherits Button

    Private _NewTag as string
    Public Property NewTag() As String

     Get
                Return _NewTag 
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _NewTag = value
            End Set


    End Property

End Class
```

Now,after compile this code and get new button and use it like the following :

```
Dim NewBtn as MyNewButton

    NewBtn.Text="New Button"
    NewBtn.NewTag="Here New tag string" ' This is the custom property
    Addhandler NewBtn.Click Addressof Btn_Click() 








 Private Sub Btn_Click()

        msgbox("New Button")
     End Sub
```

The problem Is when I click on that button the method Btn_Click() executed twice 
And solution for this  ??????    Nb. I'm using vb.net windows application not web application

Comment: What language is this?  It's customary to put the language in the tags.

Comment: Make sure Addhandler is called only once.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code does not run. `value as integer` is wrong, it must be `as String` like the property.
That corrected, I cannot reproduce your problem. I don't think it may originate in those code parts you have given.

Besides that, properties may now be a one-liner, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589%28v=vs.100%29.aspx